# How to solve NO_ROUTE_DESTINATION when connecting from two FreeSWITCH

Tags: freeswitch

I am new to FreeSWITCH and I am trying to bridge a call from two different FreeSWITCH (SwitchA -> SwitchB ).
But when I am trying to make a call, It says *NO_ROUTE_DESTINATION* .

Here is my current configuration for FreeSWITCH-A (the call originates)

**My **sip_profile/external****

```
<include>
    <gateway name="fs-test2">
        <param name="proxy" value="ipOfSwitch-B:5080"/>
        <param name="register" value="false"/>
        <param name="called-id-in-from" value="true"/>

        <variables>
            <variable name="verbose_sdb" value="true"/>
            <variable name="absolute_codec_string" value="PCMU, PCMA" direction="oubound"/>
        </variables>
    </gateway>
</include>
```

**My DialPlan**

*dialplan/default*

```
<include>

    <extension name="outbound_call">
        <condition field="destination_number" expression="^(18881)$">
            <action application="bridge" data="sofia/gateway/fs-test2/$1"/>
        </condition>
    </extension>

</include>
```

*dialplan/public*

```
<include>
   <extension name="public-did">
        <condition field="destination_number" expression="^(19991)$">
            <action application="set" data="domain_name=$${domain}"/>
            <action application="transfer" data="1000 XML default"/>
            <action application="answer"/>
            <action application="sleep" data="1000"/>
        </condition>
   </extension>
</include>
```

And here is my current configuration for FreeSWITCH-B

**My sip_profile/external**

```
<include>
   <gateway name="fs-test1">
        <param name="proxy" value="ipOfSwitch-A:5080"/>
        <param name="register" value="false"/>
        <param name="caller-id-in-from" value="true"/>
    </gateway>
</include>
```

**My dialplan**

*dialplan/default*

```
<include>
   <extension name="outbound_call">
        <condition field="destination_number" expression="^(18881)$">
            <action application="bridge" data="sofia/gateway/fs-test1/$1"/>
         </condition>
    </extension>
</include>
```

*dialplan/public*

```
<include>
    <extension name="public-did">
        <condition field="destination_number" expression="^(18881)$">
            <action application="set" data="domain_name=$${domain}"/>
            <action application="transfer" data="1000 XML default"/>
        </condition>
    </extension>
</include>
```

**This is my sofia status profile** looks like in SWITCH A-

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Profile::Gateway-Name|       Data                      | Status |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
external::fs-test2   | sip:FreeSWITCH@ipOfSwitchB:5080 | NOREG  | 
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

**This is my sofia status profile** looks like in SWITCH B-

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Profile::Gateway-Name|       Data                      | Status |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
external::fs-test1   | sip:FreeSWITCH@ipOfSwitchA:5080 | NOREG  | 
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

and when I type the command for ***sofia status gateway fs-test2*** in SWITCH A , the result looks like this:

```
Name       | fs-test2
Profile    | external
Scheme     | Digest
Realm      | ipOfSwitchB:5080
username   | FreeSWITCH
Password   | no
From       | <sip:FreeSWITCH@ipOfSwitchB:5080>
Contact    | <sip:gw+fs-test2@103.62.152.227:5080;transport=udp;gw=fs-test2>
Exten      | FreeSWITCH
To         | sip:FreeSWITCH@ipOfSwitchB:5080
Proxy      | sip:FreeSWITCH@ipOfSwitchB:5080
Status     | UP
State      | NOREG
```

After I've done all the changes , I run "reloadxml", "reload mod_sofia"

When I trigger a call(18881) from SWITCH A, there is a logs showing on SWITCH B, and it says  :

```
sofia.c:10362 sofia/external/FreeSWITCH@ipOfSWITCHB:5080 receiving invite from ipOfSWITCHB:5080 version: 1.10.6 -release-18-1ff9d0a60e 64bit call-id: fd37ba89-54d1-123a-db86-080027337ad5,
```

and the moment the call ended from SWITCHA, the logs shows on SWITCHA as:

```
switch_core_state_machine.c:276 Dialplan [default] not found, skipping
switch_core_state_machine.c:312 No Route, Aborting
 switch_core_state_machine.c:313 Hangup sofia/external/1000@ipOfSWITCHA [CS_ROUTING] [NO_ROUTE_DESTINATION]
```

there is also a log showing on SwitchB:

```
sofia.c:8641 Hangup sofia/external/18881 [CS_CONSUME_MEDIA] [NO_ROUTE_DESTINATION]
mod_dptools.c:3643 Originate Failed.  Cause: NO_ROUTE_DESTINATION
switch_channel.c:4942 Hangup sofia/external/FreeSWITCH@ipOfSwitchB:5080 [CS_EXECUTE] [NO_ROUTE_DESTINATION]
```

Am I missing something?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're dialing 18881 from SwitchA?


What happens on SwitchA when you run "sofia status profile external" or "sofia status gateway fs-test2"? It could be your config wasn't reloaded.  reloadxml often isn't enough for gateway updates.

Do you see the call coming in on SwitchB?

Comment: @user1278519 Hi, I edited my question above, I included the result when I run "sofia status profile" and the logs of both switches.

Comment: OK indeed it looks like the gateway loaded, and it's reaching the second server.
Perhaps it's as 'Lin Yu Cheng' said: can you show us the whole log on SwitchB?
On "/log 7" it will show all of how it's processing the call. Learning to read that was how I actually learned to use the dialplan.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what happened when SIP INVITE send into your Switch-B:

1. reach extension "public-did", and transfer to extension "1000" of default context.
2. since you don't have extension "1000" in default context, so you got error "No Route"